# SfdcSqlException: ORA-04023

Tags: soql, error, error-messages

This is the problem I am getting.

> System.UnexpectedException: common.exception.SfdcSqlException: ORA-04023: Object select /*Apex.Class.YourBatch.start: line 108*/ *
> from (select "Id",
> "SAPId__c"
> from (select /*+ ordered index(ind IECUSTOM_UNIQUE_VALUE_STRING) use_nl(cft) index(cft PKACCOUNT_CFDATA) use_nl(t) index(t pkaccount) */
> t.deleted "IsDeleted_gen_1",
> cft.val116 "SAPId__c",
> t.account_id "Id",
> ind.string_value "SAPId__c.X"
> from core.custom_unique_value ind,
> sales.account_cfdata cft,
> sales.account t
> where (ind.entity_id = cft.account_cfdata_id)
> and (t.account_id = cft.account_cfdata_id)
> and (ind.organizatio could not be validated or authorized
> ; [conn=STANDARD:1:1:1299:58655]

**Context:** Using a Batch Apex and it gets this error in the line below.

> [SELECT Id, SapId__c FROM Account WHERE SapId__c IN: sapIds]

It used to work but now something went wrong. What could be the problem?

-Edit-

As @Derek F said problem was never me :P

After a week of confusion, ORA-04023 has left my sandbox, hopefully for good! The problem stemmed from the sapID__c field not being able to be filtered with a custom list or set of strings. It seems this custom field was somehow corrupted.

Comment: "ORA" errors happen in the Oracle database(s) that Salesforce uses to underpin SObjects, SOQL, and so on. As such, you're not really going to find much help or information. This is (unfortunately) almost certainly something you need to open a ticket with Salesforce's official Customer Support for.

Comment: Looks like your session or even your org is corrupted in some way; you should never see this sort of error normally. Contact Salesforce Support.

Comment: Thank you for feedbacks. Looks like the problem is because of set<string> I am using in SOQL. "IN: sapIds" removing this addition cuts of the problem. Will post details later

Comment: @YCS I've just started getting the same error yesterday, out of the sudden. Did you find any solution yet? Obviously removing the filtering is not an option :) I've noticed that it happens when filtering on Unique fields and for me it only happens in tests

Comment: This is in a Sandbox for me and it started with a test then spread to other batch apexs. @BartoszŚliwiński

Comment: My new finding is that when I perform a query on Custom Object and filter on a Unique field - it fails if the value I'm filtering on does not exist in database. I've created SF Support Case, we'll see what it brings.

Comment: @BartoszŚliwiński This problem was a week old. But today it disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give the topic a bit of closure - I was in contact with Salesforce Support and turns out the issue was caused by some SF maintenance of a few instances (ours was [CS332](https://status.salesforce.com/instances/CS332/maintenances)). According to SF Support, it started happening around 16/17th of March and as @YCS stated in the comment - it is now resolved.

Comment: We also use CS332. Thx for the insight neighbour!